# MySQL efficiency - do repeated statements in one query get executed multiple times?

Tags: mysql, sql

In a query such as this:

```
SELECT 
AVG(var1) AS var1_average,
AVG(var2) AS var2_average,
(
 AVG(var1) + 
 AVG(var2)
)/2.0 AS total_average
FROM readings
```

do statements like **AVG(var1)** that appear multiple times get executed multiple times, or are they more efficiently cached internally?

My question comes from trying to understand performance / efficiency. Is it better to write this as some form of subquery? How big a difference will it make?

Comment: use `EXPALIN` to look at the plan and find out.

Comment: I wouldn't know, but maybe you can try. Add a couple of hundred of those statements in a query and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Adding several hundred of them definitely makes a difference, but that might just be down to how long it takes to parse the query

Comment: @Jodrell I'm not clear how EXPLAIN shows if a repeated statement is executed more than once. Could you please give details?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very arcane area of optimization, the optimizing of common sub expressions.  In your example, it makes little difference.  The `group by` sorts the data, which is much more expensive than doing the average.

There are other calculations, such as `count(distinct)`, that are more expensive.  In that case, your question becomes more obvious.

Stephen's solution of comparing to a subquery probably works well enough in this case.  However, the subquery incurs a lot of overhead itself, because it creates a temporary table.  So, you are not comparing apples and apples.

If you really want to compare the difference, do the following comparison.  Compare your query:

```
SELECT AVG(var1) AS var1_average, AVG(var2) AS var2_average,
       (AVG(var1) + AVG(var2))/2.0 AS total_average
FROM readings;
```

To:

```
SELECT AVG(var1) AS var1_average, AVG(var2) AS var2_average
FROM readings;
```

You'll probably find that they take about the same time.  If not, you might be able to use the subquery approach.  Or you might decide to do the average calculation at the application level.

Answer (score 1):

Try to compare the execution times between:

```
SELECT 
AVG(var1) AS var1_average,
AVG(var2) AS var2_average,
(
 AVG(var1) + 
 AVG(var2)
)/2.0 AS total_average
FROM readings
```

And:

```
SELECT
    (var1_average+var2_average)/2.0 AS total_average
    var1_average,
    var2_average
FROM (
    SELECT 
        AVG(var1) AS var1_average,
        AVG(var2) AS var2_average
    FROM readings
) as tmp
```

Make sure to run them multiple times and also add `SQL_NO_CACHE` to get meaningful results.

*NOTE:*
  The second query should have a small overhead since mysql will create a temp table but this will be irrelevant if there are a lot of records in `readings` table.